# Find the sum of infinite series when ever the series converges.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Hi I am trying to find the sum of this infinite series whenever it converges. I have tried the common ratio technique but my work doesn't match the answers. I would appreciate any help with explanation.

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (2\cos^2 \theta)^k $$

Comment: Where we have convergence, the sum is $\frac{2\cos^2\theta}{1-2\cos^2\theta}$. This can be rewritten in various ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a geometric series. So answer is
$$
\frac{2\cos^2 \theta}{1-2\cos^2 \theta}
$$
whenever
$$
\cos^2 \theta <\frac12
$$

Answer (score 1):

For fixed $\theta$, the sum is just the geometric series for $t=2\cos^2 \theta$. For $t\geq 0$, geometric series $\sum_{k\geq 1} t^k$ is convergent if and only if $t<1$. So the sum converges to $\dfrac{t^1}{1-t}=\dfrac{2\cos^2 \theta}{1-2\cos^2 \theta}$ when $t=2\cos^2 \theta <1$.